# Rails Installation error :The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, open-source

i m installing Rails 3 on my windows.
I installed latest ruby 2.0.0, and i updated gems.
but when i installing rails by using gem install rails , successful message has come but at last i found

```
 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
     The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools

    Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
    from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
    at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

plese help me...

Comment: tried doing what its saying? See this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100891/the-json-native-gem-requires-installed-build-tools`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also gone through the same problem. After doing a lot of research, I found a solution that works.

Run this command:

```
pik list
```

It should show you

```
187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
193: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
200: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
```

If it's not pointing to Ruby version 200 then run the following:

```
pik use 200
```

Now run the following to enhance DevKit to your installed Ruby:

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

Finally, run the following:

```
gem install rails
```

This will install latest Rails version 4 for Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 33):

As error message said, you need to install Ruby DevKit which can be obtained from RubyInstaller.org. (also need to check suitable Devkit version from there..)

And extract the DevKit zip file into somewhere (you are using windows then-> : c:\xxxx)
Navigate to c:\xxxx and run "ruby dk.rb init" and then "ruby dk.rb install"..

And try to re-insall rails..

I hope this helps,

Comment: So these instructions are incomplete then? Just says install ruby, then: gem install rails.  http://rubyonrails.org/download

Comment: It worked for me as well after fiddling a lot! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

I also gone through the same problem. :) but is my first install of ruby on windows  and "pik" is not avaible
  so i place me in the devkit folder  and try : ruby dk.rb init 
and 
ruby dk.rb install
 and finaly 
gem install rails
 ...
no more faillure

Answer (score 1):

[github.com](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) tells us that:

The path to your RUBY_INSTALL_DIR must not contain any whitespaces (like in “C:\Program Files\Ruby193”). This is very important because whitespaces in the path to your ruby installation will cause certain error messages as soon as you try to install gems which require the DevKit.

This solved the problem of this kind for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to like this answer but if you go:
  https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit
like it says in the message it actually helps you quite a bit.

It tells you to install the Development-Kit then cd to the directory that you put it the run “ruby dk.rb init” and “ruby dk.rb install” and when it finishes then you can run "gem install rails" and it simply works.

Easy to miss as I didn't see it the first time either