# Error installing json gem: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby, json, windows, rubygems

When i'm trying to install this gem it claims that i need to have a devkit installed although i am sure i do have it. It also suggests that i need to update my systems variables in PATH which i have directly linked to the devkit file in ruby. I have seen other questions on Stack Overflow and they didn't work with my issue.
here is the full error message:

```
C:\Users\Mahamoud>gem install json
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

I've tried uninstalling and re installing ruby and still no result.
i have my devkit located in the C:\Ruby193\bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are detailed steps for installing DevKit here:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

And to test that your installation is working correctly, you are supposed to try this:

```
gem install json --platform=ruby
```

So, you should already have json installed. Instead of reinstalling ruby, I would try reinstalling DevKit...and follow the directions EXACTLY.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still didn't solve my problem. I found a way to go around without the json gem.

Comment: @Mahamo101, Your comment is way too vague.  The goal is to help someone else in the future.  Please post how you solved your problem. Future searchers might want to try the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100891/the-json-native-gem-requires-installed-build-tools, and if the problem can't be solved, then you can try installing the json_pure gem.

Comment: @Mahamo101, Can you at least post your PATH?

Comment: All i did was i took my output and wrote next to it .to_json and it gave me a weird text then i found an online website that translates this text to a readable format. sing this website.
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I don't understand why this has to be so complicated. I just opened the *detailed steps* and they are complete gibberish. wtf!