# Error while starting server in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to ruby on rails, here i am trying to install ruby on rails on 64 bit windows 7.

after running the command `rails new app_name`, i did `cd app_name`, and then `rails server`.but then  am getting below error in command prompt.

how can i solve this error?

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed
in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If i run bundle install, i am getting

```
C:\Users\walnut>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.................
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Try running `bundle install`

Comment: Similar question as I see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8101167/140693

Comment: This could help as well - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25069456/140693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can try this solution :

1. install rubyinstaller-1.9.3(i did try with latest version, but having some problem, just try using this installer first - download [Here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) )
2. install DevKit(download [Here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)) - Find the `For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3:` text inside those download page as we install ruby-1.9.3.

   - You can follow [this](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) for devKit installation **or**
   - follow this:

     - After download, run it to extract it somewhere (permanent). Then cd to it, run`ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb` install to bind it to ruby installations in your path.
3. After that, type `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`
4. When finish all step above, you can create rails project at any place by using this command `rails new yourProject`
5. If have an error something like `"An error occurred while installing rake (*any version), and Bundler cannot continue."`, refer this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl)** or follow this step :

   - Download [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem), and put inside ruby installation folder, usually something like this path `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\ssl_certs`.
6. Again, try type `rails new yourProject`(previous one failed).
7. Finish, Usually the error about bundle install already gone. Have a luck my friend.
8. Lastly, enter into `yourProject` dir, then run `rails server`.

I'm also having dificult time when first install on windows platform, hope this help. Please note that, if you are using other than default database using by rails(sqlite3) like `mysql, postgresql, etc`, then you need to install the right gem for that to work. just run `gem install theRightGemForDatabase`.