# Error while opening the IE browser through watir

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir, watir-webdriver

When I try to open/attach to an IE browser, I am getting the below error.  I have the Watir gem installed in my system, but still I am facing the below error.  Earlier, they were no issues when I tried to open the IE browser.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> include Watir
=> Object
irb(main):004:0> @ie=Watir::IE.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::IE
        from (irb):4
```

My system configurations:

```
Windows-7
IE-8
```

Comment: What changed between when this worked and when it stopped? Did you upgrade your version of Watir?

Comment: yep justin just now I installed watir-webdriver-performance as well as updated the gems due to which I got Watir(5.0.0) installed prior to watir(1.6.7)

Comment: unless you are doing something really unusual you should only need to require watir, not include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Watir::IE` has been deprecated in the newer versions of Watir (Classic). In the current version of Watir (Classic and Webdriver), it needs to be `Watir::Browser`.

In other words:

```
@ie = Watir::Browser.new
```

Comment: even I tried with the above syntax but I got the following error  LoadError: no such file to load -- watir-classic from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:121:in `gem_original_require'from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:121:in `require'from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
41:in `load_driver'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
33:in `load_driver_for'from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
6:in `initia

Comment: Can you check your list of installed gems, `gem list`, to see if you have Watir-Classic installed? It should have been installed when installing Watir, but it sounds like it was not.

Comment: I dont have watir-classic installed in my system currently I have Watir(5.0.0,1.6.7) versions installed so which version of watir-classic u want me to installed

Comment: Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing watir-classic:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.,I got the error while installing watir-classic

Comment: I guess the question is what is your goal? Are you trying to get the latest version of Watir-Classic (ie the newest version of Watir v1.6.7) or are you trying to switch to Watir-Webdriver's IE?

Comment: I want it to waork as earlier as we use to open the browser @ie=Watir::IE.new

Comment: Then I would suggest installing the newest version of Watir-Classic. It looks like one of its dependencies, Nokogiri needs you to also install a version of Ruby that is greater than 1.9.2. If you do not want to upgrade Ruby, you could try manually installing an older version of Nokogiri that is compatible with Ruby 1.8.

Comment: nokogiri -v 1.5.10 I have installed nokogiri 1.5.10 which is compatible with the ruby 1.8.7 but still I am facing the similar issue

Comment: Similar issue... meaning which issue?

Comment: Unintialized constant if i use 'IE' where as load error issue if I use 'Browser'

Comment: LoadError: no such file to load -- watir-classic
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:121:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require
.rb:121:in `require'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
41:in `load_driver'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
33:in `load_driver_for'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-5.0.0/lib/watir/loader.rb:
6:in `initialize'
        from (irb):5:in `new'

Comment: It still sounds like you have not installed Watir-Classic.

Comment: C:\Users\>gem install watir-classic
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir-classic:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
creating extconf.h
creating Makefilenmake  clean'nmake' is not recognized as an internalor external command,operable program or batch file.nmake
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make failed,while trying to install the watir-classic I got the above mention error

Comment: There are a number of StackOverflow questions with this error. Have you tried some of their answers? The most common answer seems to suggest you are missing the Ruby Development Kit.

Comment: Hey @ Justin Ko I have gone through some of the questions on stackoverfflow but couldn't resolve it can u suggest ........

Comment: Actually I have installed the Ruby through the svn checkout is it possible to   download the ruby development kit ........

Comment: You can get it from the [RubyInstaller for Window's page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

Comment: yeah you need devkit   See the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/8100891/409820