# gem install error - json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

![Note : I have the latest compatible development kit downloaded and extracted.
Please help me how to solve it. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdx5J.png)

Comment: you would get solution from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100891/the-json-native-gem-requires-installed-build-tools

Comment: This doesn't look like a complete question to me that will be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
gem install json --platform=ruby
```

And follow [Development Kit steps](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

Comment: Step 1: Am installing rails in the directory >> sites
Step 2: Once i give rails new "appname"and then pressed enter, at the end i get the error message shown in the snapshot.
Note: Am able to create the app folder in a cloud environment, but not able to do that in my local PC. 
So how to resolve this json install error. 

Nick and amit : I tried them, not working.. its the same error.

Comment: I have extracted the devkit to C drive. and when i enter ruby dk.rb init it shows unknown directory.

and when i run "bundle install" it shows the same json error. Please help

Comment: Thank you guys i found the solution. :) It was with the extraction of dev kit. Problem solved..... Thread closed....  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 sudo gem install json --platform=ruby --verbose
```