# Error installing middleman: The 'fast_blank' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: rubygems, middleman

Can some one help me to solve this above issue i'm using windows 8.1 
trying to install middleman from command line  ?
By following this tutorial ?
https://github.com/middleman/middleman

C:>gem install middleman

**after some successfull installation**

ERROR:  Error installing middleman:
        The 'fast_blank' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'link'
at 'link'

C:>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `DevKit`.

Have you installed the `DevKit` following the instructions at [devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)?

If you have installed it, and still seeing the same error, then after installing `DevKit` you need to add it to the `PATH` so that the gem installer can call the `DevKit` executables.

Comment: In addition, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064818/1010443) to initialize `DevKit`.

Comment: If you're on Ruby 2.4 (which now uses MSYS devkit bundled with the installer) make sure you've selected option 3 in the MSYS64 installer (Install MSYS and MINGW)