# Sketchup Plugin Error, Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sketchup

I installed a sketchup plugin, and when I run it, it shows the following error:

```
Gem: InstallError: The 'sqlite3' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

C:/Program Files (x86)/SketchUp/SketchUp 2016/Tools/RubyStdLib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:12:in `rescue in block in <top (required)>'
```

Can someone please help me out with it?

Comment: Did you tried to follow the instructions ?

Comment: yes, I did still doesn't work. I dont know which ruby version to install, to get it to work. I installed 2.4, and still getting the error

Comment: Is this post related to your issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100891/the-json-native-gem-requires-installed-build-tools

Answer (score 1):

Devtools doesn't work within SketchUp's Ruby. If you need a compiled gem then you would need to compile it yourself with a matching standalone Ruby installation. Then you'd have to manually copy it into SketchUp's gem directory.